# How to get mouse press position relative to QScrollArea's widget

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qscrollarea, mouse-position, mousepress

If I have a wide widget in a QScrollArea, and I press the mouse on it, then I get a mouse position (in `mousePressEvent()`) relative to the scroll area (if I scroll, it changes).

How can I get the mouse position relative to that wide widget inside the scroll area?

I tried to use a combination of functions `mapTo()`, `parentWidget()`, `viewport()` and had no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QPoint global/local mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412879/qpoint-global-local-mapping)

Comment: @A.R.M. No, it has nothing about QScrollArea specificities.

Comment: QScrollArea is just a composed widget (QScrollArea->viewport->contained widget). The question I linked explains the basic concept of mapping points. It's not specific to QScrollArea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I've got three similiar ways that work quite fine for  me.

```
class MyWidget : public QScrollArea
{
// ...
};

void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << widget()->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());     // 1
    qDebug() << widget()->mapFrom(viewport(), event->pos()); // 2
    qDebug() << widget()->mapFromParent(event->pos());       // 3
}
```